# Error in deploying SAM script from AWS Educate account Cloud9 console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sam

I am new to using AWS and Serverless Application Model (SAM). While following the GitHub of one of the recent [AWS Virtual Workshop](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-serverless-workshop-innovator-island), I am facing problem in SAM deployment.

In particular, while following the [module 1](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-serverless-workshop-innovator-island/tree/master/1-app-deploy), these are the steps they provide (All these steps are performed from `Cloud9` terminal):

1. Find the Account Id.
   `accountId=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document | jq -r .accountId)`
2. Name the S3 bucket appending the Account Id
   `s3_deploy_bucket="theme-park-sam-deploys-${accountId}"`
3. Create the s3 bucket with that name.
   `aws s3 mb s3://$s3_deploy_bucket`
4. Go to the appropriate directory with SAM YAML file.
5. Package
   `sam package --output-template-file packaged.yaml --s3-bucket $s3_deploy_bucket`
6. Deploy
   `sam deploy --template-file packaged.yaml --stack-name theme-park-ride-times --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM`

All the steps work well until step 5. On executing step 6, after the successful creation of a few resources, I am facing an error on a particular creation and it fails. This results in a rollback and all created resources are also deleted.

`ResourceStatus`: CREATE_FAILED

`ResourceType`: AWS::Events::Rule

`LogicalResourceId`': UpdateRidesUpdateRidesEvent

`ResourceStatusReason`: User: arn:aws:sts::969009900039:assumed-role/vocstartsoft/user810955=ameya.181co205@nitk.edu.in is not authorized to perform: events:PutRule on resource:arn:aws:events:us-east-1:969009900039:rule/theme-park-ride-times-UpdateRidesUpdateRidesEvent-1C6BYBO984UL7 with an explicit deny (Service: AmazonCloudWatchEvents; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: c6d8162d-a3f1-405f-b6e8-2fd5437c4392)

Please let me the solution to this problem. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `AWS Educate Starter Account`, you have a **lot of limitations** imposed on what you can and can't do in your sandbox account.

The general list of what is allowed is:

- [AWS Services Supported with AWS Educate Starter Account](https://s3.amazonaws.com/awseducate-starter-account-services/AWS_Educate_Starter_Accounts_and_AWS_Services.pdf)

Also note that this is **not exhaustive list**:

> Some services may have **additional restrictions** as described in the table below.

The error message you got is  **an explicit deny**. This means that you aren't allowed to do what you are attempting due to limitations of the starter account.

An alternative to using the start account, is using having your account (an option only for educators on AWS Educate). This way, if you are educator, AWS Educate could provide you **credits** towards your classes. But since you use your own account, you would have full control over it.

If the error you are facing is part of a classroom or tutorial they provide, you may contact their **customer support**. If this deny prohibits you from completing their own tutorials or classrooms, they should be able to fix that.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am using a starter account. Is it possible for me to a personal account?

Comment: @AmeyaDeshpande Personal accounts are supported only if you are an educator. Sorry forgot to mention that in my answer. I will add it now.

Comment: So, a final clarification. The workshop was suggested on a personal AWS account. I started following it from my edu starter account. So, there is no way to do it from this account?